# Python serial fails

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to log serial incoming data to a tkinter frame.

This is my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import serial.tools.list_ports

#global variable that will hold the COM port
COMPort = 0


#to be used on our canvas
HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

#hardcoded baud rate
baudRate = 9600


#make our own buffer
#useful for parsing commands
#Serial.readline seems unreliable at times too
serBuffer = ""

ser = 0 #initial  value. will chane at 'on_select('

# --- functions ---

#the following two functtions are for the seria port selection, on frame 1
def serial_ports():    
    return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()

def on_select(event=None):

    global COMPort
    COMPort = cb.get()
    print(COMPort)
    # get selection from event    
    #print("event.widget:", event.widget.get())

    # or get selection directly from combobox
    #print("comboboxes: ", cb.get())
    global ser
    ser = Serial(serialPort , baudRate, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0) #ensure non-blocking



def readSerial():
    while True:
        c = ser.read() # attempt to read a character from Serial
        
        #was anything read?
        if len(c) == 0:
            break
        
        # get the buffer from outside of this function
        global serBuffer
        
        # check if character is a delimeter
        if c == '\r':
            c = '' # don't want returns. chuck it
            
        if c == '\n':
            serBuffer += "\n" # add the newline to the buffer
            
            #add the line to the TOP of the log
            log.insert('0.0', serBuffer)
            serBuffer = "" # empty the buffer
        else:
            serBuffer += c # add to the buffer
    
    root.after(10, readSerial) # check serial again soon

# --- functions ---



# --- main ---
root = tk.Tk() #here we create our tkinter window
root.title("Sensor Interface")

#we use canvas as a placeholder, to get our initial screen size (we have defined HEIGHT and WIDTH)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

#we use frames to organize all the widgets in the screen

# --- frame 1 ---
frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relheight=0.03, relwidth=1, anchor='nw') #we use relheight and relwidth to fill whatever the parent is - in this case- root

label0 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Select the COM port that the device is plugged in: ")
label0.config(font=("TkDefaultFont", 8))
label0.place(relx = 0.1, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.5)


cb = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=serial_ports())
cb.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
# assign function to cmbobox
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', on_select)
# --- frame 1 ---




# --- frame 2 ---
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff') #remove color later
frame2.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheight=0.07, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

# make a scrollbar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame2)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# make a text box to put the serial output
log = Text ( frame2, width=30, height=30, takefocus=0)
log.pack()

# attach text box to scrollbar
log.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=log.yview)

# --- frame 2 ---



# after initializing serial, an arduino may need a bit of time to reset
root.after(100, readSerial)
root.mainloop() #here we run our app
```

I get this error however:

```
    ser = Serial(serialPort , baudRate, timeout=0, writeTimeout=0) #ensure non-b
locking
NameError: name 'Serial' is not defined
```

EDIT:

When i tried:

```
from Serial import Serial
```

i got:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Serial'
```

When i tried:

```
import serial
```

i got:

```
AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'tools'
```

When i tried:

```
import Serial
```

i got:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Serial'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are importing the serial module with something like `from serial import Serial`?

Comment: I have the imp[ort statements in the beginning of my code....

Comment: The answer seems pretty self-explanatory. Where do you think `Serial` is defined? It seems like you can solve this problem by reading existing documentation.

Comment: @BryanOakley It may be self-explanatory for you, but not for me. I updated the question with four different approaches i tried and all failed.

Comment: Are you using pySerial? When I search for "serial Serial", the first result has an example showing how to use the `Serial` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Serial` class is part of the `serial` module. You import it the way you import anything else. Both of the following work, depending on your preference:

```
import serial
...
ser = serial.Serial(...)
```

-or-

```
from serial import Serial
...
ser = Serial(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried from serial import Serial but now it breaks on this line 'return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()'. The error i get is: ' return serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
NameError: name 'serial' is not defined'

Comment: @user1584421 For your case, you should use the first proposal: `import serial`.